# In a UINavigationController, Passing data from topViewController to it's previous ViewController, before TopViewController is popped

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

My UINavigationController contains 3 UIViewControllers in order A -> B -> C; C is the TopViewController.

Before I pop C, I need to pass some data (that has been gathered in C) to B. How can this be done??

Comment: Give 'C' a pointer to 'B'.  Often this is done using the [Delegate Pattern](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html).

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you could do this. One is to use delegate pattern. A good article on this can be found [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/46988/ios-design-patterns). Also you may use NSNotifications to this. You can find more info on this [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-nsnotification--mobile-10619).

Comment: In my opinion, notifications is not the correct method in this instance, however delegation for sure, or using blocks.

Comment: Yes its not recommended and its not correct. I agree. Thats why I used the word "may".